# Is there an API for cron that allows it to know which days are school breaks?

Tags: cron

For a little project I am making a payday simulator for school. I would like it to only run on days when we actually have school for obvious reasons. So I was thinking maybe there's an API for cron that gives it this functionality, have you all heard of any?

I am using [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org) for cron
Apologies if this isn't worded well!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply select all school days in this dropdown

[image]

?

Comment: Except for the breaks and holidays